# org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/support/DefaultBatchConfiguration.class cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring-batch

I have an exception when I try to launch a simple hello world application with Spring Batch

Hello,

I'm new to learn Spring Batch . I created a new application, here is my pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>helloWorld</name>
    <description>helloWorld</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I want to use the version 3 of Spring batch and not the 5 one .
I created a simple Job configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfiguration  {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilder;

    //Step 1 will execute a Tasklet (in this case it will print HelloWorld)
    @Bean
    public Step step1()
    {
        //tasklet is an interface to define the type of a step . There are two types of step

        return stepBuilder.get("Step 1")
                .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                    @Override
                    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Hello World");
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }
                }).build();

    }

    //Add this step to a job
    //A job can contain one or many steps
    @Bean
    public Job helloWorldJob (JobRepository jobRepository) {
       return  jobBuilder.get("helloWorldJob")
               .start(step1())
               .build();
    }
}
```

but when I run the app , I get this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [io.spring.batch.HelloWorldApplication]: class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/support/DefaultBatchConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:524) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:726) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:723) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:694) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:182) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:398) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:283) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0-20230328.143142-136.jar:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0-20230328.143142-136.jar:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0-20230328.143142-136.jar:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0-20230328.143142-136.jar:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0-20230328.143142-136.jar:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.spring.batch.HelloWorldApplication.main(HelloWorldApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/support/DefaultBatchConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:211) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:48) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0-20230328.143142-136.jar:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0-20230328.143142-136.jar:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:923) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:334) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:365) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:265) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:514) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Do you have any idea why I have this exception ?

Comment: I added an answer with the important details. `I want to use the version 3 of Spring batch and not the 5`: Just curious, any reason you want to use that version? v3 has been in EOL since many years now, and I would recommend using the latest and greatest v5. You can find a migration guide here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide, but if you need support, do not hesitate to reach out on GitHub, we can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing `spring-boot-starter-batch` version `3.0.5`. This means you are using Spring Boot 3, which brings Spring Batch 5, and both require Java 17 as a minimum Java version.

Spring Batch 3 on the other hand is based on Java 8 (and is not maintained anymore BTW), and you cannot use it with Spring Boot 3. You would need to downgrade Spring Boot to version 1.5.x (but this version is not maintained anymore), or upgrade Spring Batch to 5.0.x.

Here is a quick summary of Spring Boot versions and the corresponding Spring Batch versions:

- Spring Boot 3.0.x -> Spring Batch 5.0.x
- Spring Boot 2.7.x -> Spring Batch 4.3.x
- Spring Boot 1.5.x -> Spring Batch 3.0.x

Please check the support page of each project here:

- Spring Boot: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support
- Spring Batch: https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch#support

So in your case, the class `DefaultBatchConfiguration` which was introduced in Spring Batch 5 cannot be found since you are importing Spring Batch 3.0.10. This class is used by Spring Boot 3 to auto-configure Spring Batch.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and for this detailed explanation . I will use the new version of Spring batch .